# How to simulate upgrade of an Android app using appium

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, adb, appium

I am trying to test an application upgrade (install a new version while the old one still exists on the device). The scenario has the following steps:

- Install an app v1
- Perform some action in an app
- Install an app v2 without uninstalling v1 validate that the actions
  effect is still    present in the new version

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this manually on your device ? 2 apps having Same package name and activity name create conflict.

Comment: i tried it myself. what happens is that before the appium installs the second apk, it uninstalls the first apk and thats not what i want

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Because Appium needs unique Pkg name and activity name to open an app. In your case, there is conflict that which app I(Appium) should launch as there are two copies of an app if you install both apps manually.

Comment: from a look online it seems i should use adb install -r <apppackage>

Comment: not sure how to use it

Comment: It will replace app. You won't be able to install two same apps with diff versions in this way.

Comment: so basically its not possible to simulate an upgrade?

Comment: Appium doesn't support. Consider even if you get success to install two apps . But how you will tell appium which app should use. Right ?